# read file and grab integer

Tags: c#, .net

I have txt file which contains number that I want to grab. This number has prefix which can be used to identify location inside file.

```
GeneratedNumber="120"
```

Number can be of any `Int32` length value.

p.s. format of the file is .txt, one line contains more this key value pairs for example:

`<Output Change="12.13" GeneratedNumber="120" Total="99.21" />`

Comment: So what's the format of the file? Is every line of the form Name="Value"? Are all the values integers, or just the one that you're trying to get? Are there any comment lines etc?

Comment: @JonSkeet question is updated and values are integers

Comment: So it's an xml-file? Please show us the whole file (or at least a truncated version with the structure).

Comment: no, it's not an xml file, at least it has no xml extension, either it's structure reminds on xml file.

Comment: "either it's structure reminds on xml file." I don't understand what that means. Does the file contain xml formatted data or not?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain the structure of the file is similar to that of an xml file is probably what he meant to say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code. Not very elegant or the best but tested and works fine.

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "test.txt"));
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            if (s.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("generatednumber"))
            {
                string temp = s.Substring(s.ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf("generatednumber"));
                temp = temp.Substring(temp.IndexOf("\"") + 1);
                temp = temp.Substring(0,temp.IndexOf("\""));
                int yournumber;
                if (int.TryParse(temp, out yournumber))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Generated Number = ", yournumber);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've only tested this as far as the xml side but this should work (You may wish to add error handling and the conversion to integers)

```
var values = new List<string>();
using(var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    string line;
    XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        x.LoadXml(line);
        foreach(var node in x.GetElementsByTagName("Output"))
           values.Add(node.Attributes["GeneratedNumber"].Value);    
    }
}
```

Tested using:

```
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
x.LoadXml("<Output Change=\"12.13\" GeneratedNumber=\"120\" Total=\"99.21\" />");

Console.WriteLine(x.GetElementsByTagName("Output")[0]
                      .Attributes["GeneratedNumber"].Value);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
     // Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element 
     // of the array is one line of the file. 
     string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\yourFile.txt");

     foreach (string line in lines)
     {
        string sub = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("GeneratedNumber=") + 1);
        int num = int.Parse(sub.IndexOf("\""));
        // whatever you want to do with the integer
     }
```

to read the text file lines and parse the lines after the "=" sign to integers.

depend on the look of the file you might use `XmlDocument`. please read about Xml [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

Comment: Your substring is most likely going to be `"12.13" GeneratedNumber="120" Total="99.21" />` which will fail the parse

Comment: @Sayse ok, just saw the edit...

Comment: @Sayse might be, i'll ask for the full file

Answer (score 1):

This code should match your needs:

```
private static int GetNumber(string fileName)
{
    string line;
    string key = "GeneratedNumber=\"";
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
       while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
          if (line.Contains(key))
          {
             int startIndex = line.IndexOf(key) + key.Length;
             int endIndex = line.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
             return int.Parse(line.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
          }
       }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also you may be interested in these articles:

- [Using of StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
- [String methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string_methods.aspx)
- [Int32.Parse method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Use of Regular expressions is more optimum in such cases. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("path to file");
Hashtable values = new Hashtable();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("=\""))
    {
        string[] split = line.Split('=');
        values.Add(split[0], split[1].Replace("\"",""));
    }
}
// GeneratedNumber is the value of GeneratedNumber in the file.
int GeneratedNumber = Int32.Parse(values["GeneratedNumber"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string filePath = "your_file_path";
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(
    System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath),
    @"GeneratedNumber=""(\d+)""",
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

int num = match.Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) : 0;
```

Assuming there's only one instance of that number in the file or you want to grab only the first one even if there are multiple.

Comment: For multiple instances, just do match.NextMatch() repeatedly until it returns null or match.Success returns false